# System Center 2012 R2 DPM loading tapes from library out of order

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, tape, system-center, scdpm

I have a System Center 2012 R2 Data Protection Manager (DPM) configured and working properly. The server has a SAS Tape Library with 24 tapes, and the DPM shows all tapes.

But when a backup to tape is done, the tape library doesn't load the first tape (from slot #1), it loads the last tape (from the last full slot).

This is the default behavior? How can I set the order to load the tapes?

Tks.

PS: Sorry for my english.
I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: for control... the slots has numbers, and the tapes has labels, and it must match the order of using it, if possible.

Comment: I don't think DPM can do that, but I also don't understand why you would need DPM to discriminate amongst tapes available for writing.